# Partials doesn't resolve variables passed into it

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm creating a task that will periodically send some emails to users (of a portal that the task is concern).
To create an email I use partials.

*app/templates/_email_plain.php:*

```
Hi, <?= $login ?>
```

*app/templates/_email_html.php:*

```
Hi, <?= $login ?>
```

Unfortunately, after

```
$plain = get_partial('global/email_plain', array('login' => 'John Doe'));
$html = get_partial('global/email_html', array('login' => 'John Doe'));
```

and both sending it via email or var_dump()'ing in the task console I receive

```
Hi, <?= $login ?>
```

variable `$login` is unprocessed.

Have anyone came across such problem?
How to solve it?

---

`short_open_tag` is enabled -> I use it in whole project and it works. However I've changed all the `<?=` to `<?php echo` to just-to-check and it magically(?) works. This leads me to believe that Symfony CLI doesn't read main `php.ini`.

It's not the end of the problem.
The task should also send some newsletter with top rated articles from the past week.

```
$params = array('popular_articles' => $popular_articles, 'popular_threads' => $popular_threads);


Mailer::SendBulkMessage(
     $this->getMailer(), 
     get_partial('global/email_weekly_newsletter_plain', $params ),
     get_partial('global/email_weekly_newsletter_html', $params ),
     $users,
    'Weekly newsletter'
);
```

where `$articles` is `Doctrine_Collection`.

After
`$partial = get_partial('global/partial, $partialParameters)`
where I print title of the articles I get in a `foreach` loop I get an error saying that I'm using `->getTitle()` on a non-object.

(in partial, the `$articles` class is `sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator` )

---

Problematic loop from the partial:

```
<h3>Most commented articles</h3>
<? foreach( $popular_articles as $article ): //Line#10 ?>
    <?php link_to( $article->getTitle(), $article->getUrlPath(), array('class' => 'newsletter-article-item') ); ?><br /> 
<? endforeach; ?>


<h3>Hottest discussions</h3>
<? foreach( $popular_threads as $thread ): ?>
    <?php link_to( $thread->getTitle(), absoluteRoute::getRouteForForum('forum_thread_view', array('id' => $thread->getId())), array('class' => 'newsletter-article-item') ); ?><br />
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Above yields

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object in P:\ath\to\project\apps\content\templates\_email_weekly_newsletter_html.php on line 11

Call Stack:
    0.0004     629696   1. {main}() P:\ath\to\project\symfony:0
    0.0055     985544   2. include('P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\command\cli.php') P:\ath\to\project\symfony:14
    0.6824    9908768   3. sfSymfonyCommandApplication->run() P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\command\cli.php:20
    0.6841    9910728   4. sfTask->runFromCLI() P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\command\sfSymfonyCommandApplication.class.php:76
    0.6841    9911008   5. sfBaseTask->doRun() P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\task\sfTask.class.php:97
    0.7111   10729624   6. weeklyParentNewsletterTask->execute() P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\task\sfBaseTask.class.php:68
    1.4238   25474480   7. get_partial() P:\ath\to\project\lib\task\weeklyParentNewsletterTask.class.php:76
    1.4255   25479424   8. sfPartialView->render() P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\helper\PartialHelper.php:220
    1.4265   25479784   9. sfPHPView->renderFile() P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\view\sfPartialView.class.php:124
    1.4277   25536920  10. require('P:\ath\to\project\apps\content\templates\_email_weekly_newsletter_html.php') P:\ath\to\project\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\view\sfPHPView.class.php:75
```

---

### Solution

According to first problem, Symfony CLI has different `php.ini` than apache module.
I was that used to use shor_opening_tag that I didn't notice, that apart from *printing-php-statements* all others should include `<?php` instead of `<?`.
That's why foreach loop couldn't iterate through `$popular_articles` and others.

Thank for your attention.

Comment: Does it work when using the more conventional `<?php echo $login; ?>` perhaps this has to do with the `short_open_tag` setting

Comment: `short_open_tag` is enabled -> I use it in whole project and it works. However I've changed it earlier to just-to-check and it magically works. This leads me to believe that Symfony CLI doesn't read main `php.ini`.

It's not the end of the problem yet. More in main post.

Comment: On my configuration, the php.ini file for the cli is this one : /etc/php5/cli/php.ini . But sf2 can make some ini_set if it wants to. You can check the runtime values of the settings with ini_get()

Comment: Why not show the partial with the foreach loop? It might be helpful, don't you agree?

Comment: Of course it might be helpful :) Updated.

Comment: I can't find any `$articles` variable in the partial you put in your post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've obviously written that from memory.
Actual lines from my weeklyParentNewsletterTask.php I'm pasting as an post update.

Comment: Which line is line 11? There are still references to `$articles` in your question.

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you for involvement, I would probably keep it unsolved till deadline..

Answer (score 1):

According to first problem, ***Symfony CLI has different php.ini than apache module***. I was that used to use shor_opening_tag that I didn't notice, that apart from printing-php-statements all others should include `<?php` instead of `<?`. That's why foreach loop couldn't iterate through $popular_articles and others.

Thank for your attention.